# How to add "HDR" to EXIF in Lightroom Classic?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, hdr

Is there a way to add the fact that an image was crated using HDR to a photo's EXIF data in Lightroom Classic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If EXIF is not a hard requirement you can store it in the IPTC metadata as a (hierarchical) keyword.